# Setting up DNSMasq to supply different DNS servers to set address ranges on a DD-WRT router

Tags: dd-wrt, dnsmasq, parental-controls

I have set up parental controls on my DD-WRT router using the instructions [here](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Parental_control). Basically it has parent's devices and children's devices set up into different address ranges and then has you set up OpenDNS as the DNS server to provide content filtering.

The only problem is that it skips the instructions for allowing parent's devices to use alternate DNS servers to avoid filtering other than having you set up default DNS servers on each individual device. Since those devices include phones, smart TVs, and things of that nature I'd prefer to set this up at the router level.

Is there a way to set up DNSMasq's additional options so that devices assigned addresses between 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.99 are sent to Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4) while devices above that range are assigned to OpenDNS' servers?

My current Additional DNSMasq Options are

```
no-resolv
server=208.67.222.222
server=208.67.222.220
```

There seems to be a way to do it via `iptables` hinted at on DD-WRT's [OpenDNS wiki page](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenDNS) but I'd rather keep DNS stuff confined to the DNS server if possible. Besides, I don't trust myself to get the iptables syntax correct.

This seems like it should be fairly simple but there is enough dissent in the [DNSMasq wiki page](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_as_DHCP_server) that it might be trickier than I expect. Am I going down the wrong path here?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you identify hosts by something known when the DHCP request is made - the MAC address.  Then the config specifies whatever options for that MAC if there is something in the config file, otherwise it checks for an existing lease and either renews or issues a new lease.

So for dnsmasq you have to "tag" devices by MAC address into groups, then configure certain groups to have certain DHCP options - like dns servers, default gateway, etc.

Here's an older answer that has good examples of the actual syntax -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467430/dnsmasq-tags-and-conditional-dns-server